# CURL communication with Facebook's graph not working

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-opengraph

everyone.

I have the following issue:

I'm using curl to get some info from facebook's graph (and this used to work until just a few days ago), but now I just get an empty answer.
The request is quite simple:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=XXX&access_token=YYY
```

The ids parameter is just a list of ids for elements in the graph (in this case, application requests). When I copy/paste the url on a browser, it works, but when using curl it gets stuck without an answer.

The full code for the curl call is:

```
require 'php/facebook.php';


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => 'XXX',
            'secret' => 'YYY',
    ));


    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com?ids=".$_POST['data']."&access_token=".$_POST['access_token'];

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $results;
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

try {} graph.facebook.com/ with trailing slash

```
 $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=".$_POST['data']."&access_token=".$_POST['access_token'];
```

also i am unsure where you are trying to retrieve the post from so you could try request method instead.

```
 $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=".$_REQUEST['data']."&access_token=".$_REQUEST['access_token'];
```

**example ajax call to php:**

```
// get albums

function showAlbums(pageid,limit,offset){
thealbums = "albums";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    document.getElementById("albums").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET","plugins.albums.php?pageid="+pageid+"&limit="+limit+"&offset="+offset+"",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

---

Try for cURL:

---

```
function GetCH(){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com?ids=".$_POST['data']."&access_token=".$_POST['access_token']");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS,20000);
if(substr($url,0,8)=='https://'){
    // The following ensures SSL always works. A little detail:
    // SSL does two things at once:
    //  1. it encrypts communication
    //  2. it ensures the target party is who it claims to be.
    // In short, if the following code is allowed, CURL won't check if the 
    // certificate is known and valid, however, it still encrypts communication.
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
}
$sendCH = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $sendCH;
};
$ThisId = GetCH();
echo $ThisId;
```

Comment: Tried it, but still nothing. The stranger part is that if I paste the exact same url I'm using on curl in a browser, it works like a charm.

Comment: where are you trying to request the data from, the rest of the code?  "where is $_POST['data'] being posted from.

Comment: The frontend for the app. It uses AJAX to communicate with the PHP.
By the way, the generated URL is correct, as I tried it in the browser and it works.

Comment: i ran into a similar problem with a plugin i am developing at https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/photofeed.php  I resolved by adding the AJAX to the page staticly and making sure the call being made came from the same domain as the php and relative to the canvas url.

Comment: I would have to say, do a print on the url the ajax is passing and make sure nothing is being left out or encoded.

Comment: I did, and the url works fine when used somewhere else (a browser, for example).

Comment: thats odd, hate to ask but can you edit in the ajax & php code you are using?  Might be able to catch the error in the auth code.  I posted a curl snippet i use to get my app access tokens, try curling with the snippet.

Comment: Well, turn out it was a different problem altogether. IPTables was blocking the communication. Thanks a lot for your help though!

Comment: Awesome you got this, from what you had described i could not see why it would not work.